# Lossless grayscale JPEG "color" inversion?

Tags: colors, jpeg, libjpeg

Imagemagick can invert the colors of a JPEG like so:

```
mogrify -negate image.jpg
```

However, that's not lossless.  My intuition says that color inversion should be doable in a lossless fashion, at least for grayscale images, but I know hardly anything about JPEG. Hence my questions:

- Is lossless JPEG grayscale inversion possible in theory?
- If so, is libjpeg or any other software out there able to do it?

Comment: Why do you think it's not lossless? But if you're inverting in sRGB you _can't_ lossless inversion simply because of rounding issues.

Comment: If you want lossless, don't use JPEG, use PGM or LZW compressed TIF.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The source is JPEG, the target requires JPEG - there's not much of a choice for me.

Comment: From the Imagemagick forum: ImageMagick recompresses the image even when simply flipping, flopping, or copying a JPEG. There are other applications that do it losslessly, without recompressing, such as the "jpegtran" application that comes with the JPEG library.

Comment: @Bonzo Yeah, if only rotation is required, then I'm in fact using jpegtran. I didn't expect ImageMagick to do lossless stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPEG encodes images as a series of entropy coded deltas across MCUs (minimum coded units - 8x8 blocks of DCT values) and entropy coded quantized DCT coefficients within each MCU. To do something like inverting the pixel values (even if grayscale) would involve decoding the entropy coded bits, modifying the values and re-encoding them since you can't "invert" entropy coded DCT values. There isn't a one to one matching of entropy coded lengths for each value because the bits are encoded based on the statistical probability and the magnitude/sign of quantized values. The other problem is that the coded DCT values exist in the frequency domain. I'm not a mathematician, so I can't say for sure if there is a simple way to invert the spatial domain values in the frequency domain, but I think at best it's really complicated and likely the quantization of the values will interfere with a simple solution. The kind of things you can do losslessly in JPEG files is rotate, crop and less well known operations such as extracting a grayscale image from a color image. Individual pixel values can't be modified without having to decode and recode the MCUs which incurs the "loss" in JPEG quality.

Answer (score 2):

It's not lossless because there is not a 1:1 match between the gamuts of the RGB and YCbCr colorspaces used in JPEG. If you start with an RGB value that is within YCbCR and flip it, you may get a value outside the YCbCr colorspace range that will end up getting clamped.

Comment: I'm only interested in grayscale JPEGs, that's certainly worth mentioning.

Comment: Then the effect should be greatly lessened. However, the quantization process is still likely to introduce changes, even with identical coefficients.